# Create structs from array elements based on index and value

Tags: matlab

Is there a more elegant way to express the following code (e.g. without explicit for-loop)?

```
P = [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4];
% pre-allocate symbols array of struct
symbols = repmat(struct('probability', 0, 'indices', []), length(P), 1);
for i =1:length(P)
   symbols(i) = struct('probability', P(i), 'indices', i); 
end
```

P.S.: I am using the symbols to implement huffman coding, if anyone is interested.

**Edit:** Inspired by one of the comments, I might just end up doing this

```
P = [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4];
symbols = [
    [0.1 1];
    [0.2 2];
    [0.3 3];
    [0.4 4];
];
% access probability:
symbols(i)(1)
% access indices:
symbols(i)(2:end)
```

So

```
symbols = [P(:) (1:length(P))']
```

**Edit2:** For completeness, here is the entire code I'm using (huffman code)

```
function [c,h,w]=huffman(P)

assert(abs(sum(P) - 1) < 10e-6, "Probabilities must sum up to 100%");

% compute entropy
h = sum(P .* (-log2(P)));
% each row corresponds to the probability in P
c = cell(length(P), 1); % codes are represent as numerical vectors for bits

P = sort(P, 'descend');
% Preallocate 'symbols' for each probability
% A symbol is used to represent dummy "fused" probabilities as well
% size(symbols) == 1xlength(P) initially
% IMPORTANT: sort P first descending
symbols = struct('probability', num2cell(P), 'indices', num2cell(1:length(P)));
%symbols = repmat(struct('probability', 0, 'indices', []), length(P), 1);
%for i =1:length(P)
%   symbols(i) = struct('probability', P(i), 'indices', i); 
%end

while length(symbols) > 1
    % select the two lowest probabilities and add them
    % O(n) insert worst case vs log(n) binary search...
    last = symbols(end);
    preLast = symbols(end-1);
    % Build the code words by prepending bits
    c(last.indices) = cellfun(@(x)[0 x], c(last.indices), 'UniformOutput', false);
    c(preLast.indices) = cellfun(@(x)[1 x], c(preLast.indices), 'UniformOutput', false);
    % Insert dummy symbol representing combined probability of the two
    % lowest probabilities
    probSum = last.probability + preLast.probability;
    newSymbol = struct('probability', probSum, 'indices', [last.indices preLast.indices]);
    pos = find([symbols.probability] < probSum, 1);
    % insert dummy symbol and remove the two symbols which belong to it
    symbols = [symbols(1:pos-1) newSymbol symbols(pos:end-2)];
end
assert(length(symbols) == 1 && abs(symbols(1).probability - 1) < 10e-6, "Probability of tree root must add up to 100%");
% compute average codeword length
w = sum(cellfun('length', c) .* P(:));
```

I think using numerical arrays instead of structs and storing 0 as "no index" is more work, because I have to ensure all index arrays are properly padded with zeros and to call find(indices > 0) before using them. So I'll skip that for now.

This is about 3x as fast as some [random code](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31354-huffman-coding?focused=5188750&tab=function) I found on the internet, so it can't be terrible.

**Edit 3:** Matter of fact, it is about 40% faster than the huffmandict from the Communication Systems Toolbox, so yeah there you go. Either I'm missing something or they don't care about performance.

Comment: I would just stick to using `P` by itself. Using a struct like this in MATLAB is not efficient.

Comment: @CrisLuengo P isn't good enough, I create new probabilities by adding elements from P, but I need to still keep track of the original elements from P that make up the summed probability. That's why I store the indices into P which make um the summed probability. Also I can't modify P (so the indices stay valid) so I create a new array with the probabilities. I could use an array, first element = probability and (2:end) == indices.. good idea

Comment: I didn't know that the indices arrays were supposed to grow. You can do (2:end), or just keep two arrays. If you indices for each element of `P` grow at different rates, you can use zeros as "not used", or you can do a cell array: `indices{i}(:)`. But in that last case, you might as well go with the struct approach. In general, numeric arrays are much more efficient both in time it takes the interpreter to retrieve an element and in amount of memory used (since each element in the struct array is an array, with its own header overhead).

Comment: @CrisLuengo Ah you are right, I forgot about the growing at various rates, so a matrix is inconvenient. I can't pass 0 as indices, so I would have to select find(indices > 0) or so. Not sure if that's faster in a way. I will post the full code when I'm done...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
symbols = struct('probability', num2cell(P), 'indices', num2cell(1:length(P)));
```

or (Octave only, not MATLAB):

```
symbols = repmat(struct('probability', 0, 'indices', []), length(P), 1);
[symbols.probability] = num2cell(P){:};
[symbols.indices] = num2cell(1:length(P)){:};
```

Comment: The second syntax works in Octave, but not in MATLAB. You can't do `(){}` there.

Comment: The first one does (almost, dimensions swapped) the same as my manual loop, so I will likely accept it.